# Free linting tool for Verilog

Tags: fpga, verilog, xilinx, programmable-logic, quartus-ii

Is there an opensource linting tool for Verilog. I've seen HDL companion and other but they all come with a price tag.

Comment: Can an open source Verilog linting tool be designed collectively or is any group working on it?

Answer (score 5):

The best tool I know for linting Verilog is [Verilator](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilator). Check the --lint-only option if you don't need the simulation.